# Parallel optimization of a checksum algorithm?

Tags: c#-4.0, parallel-processing, crc

The below code sample is an implementation of CRC-CCITT that I'm using in one of my projects.

```
public static unsafe ushort CRC(byte * it, byte * end)
            {
                unchecked
                {
                    ushort crc = 0xFFFF;
                    ushort quick = 0;

                for (;;)
                {
                    ushort tmp = (ushort)((crc >> 8) ^ (*it));
                    crc <<= 8;

                    quick = (ushort)(tmp ^ (tmp >> 4));
                    crc ^= quick;

                    quick <<= 5;
                    crc ^= quick;

                    quick <<= 7;
                    crc ^= quick;

                    if (it == end)
                        break;
                    it++;
                }
                return crc;
            }
        }
```

The CRC-CCITT uses the following polynominal formula :

```
 (X^16 + X^12 + X^5 + 1)
```

Q: The above polynominal is nothing more then a series of add/multiplication operations. The basic laws of mathematics state that add/multiply ops are interchangeable etc. so expressions like :

`SUM(from 1 to 10) == SUM(from 1 to 5) + SUM(from 6 to 10)` are true.

I need to optimize the above code, it is probably the most frequently called thing in my project, (120 times/sec at least). Having considered the above, would this be doable with a CRC checksum ? I'm considering using Parallel.For(...) to do the trick, does that even make sense? Anyone have any suggestions?

Update :

120 times per connection actually. I'm handling at least 15 simultaneous incoming connections with datarates of 120[Hz] etc. Byte arrays can vary - theoretical max = 65k bytes, but that's rarely the case, most often it's circa 1k bytes.

Comment: How long time does it take on average to execute it for you? I'm concerned that the creation and joining of the threads might cost more than what you gain

Comment: 120 times/second? Really? That's not too bad. Have you profiled it?

Comment: How long is the byte array on which you're doing this operation?  That will be a major determining factor as to whether the parallel overhead makes any difference in speed...

Comment: 120 times per connection actually. I'm handling at least 15 simultaneous connections with datarates of 120Hz etc. Byte arrays can vary - theoretical max = 65k bytes, but that's rarely the case, most often it's circa 1k bytes.

Comment: You need a lookup table, not parallelism. With a lookup the operation per byte comes down to an XOR and an assignment (assuming the lookup is in CPU cache), which I guess modern CPU's can do in 1 cycle.

Answer (score 0):

Could this solve your problem?
(Sorry, I don't know how to circumvent a deleted post!)

```
//  inspired by http://automationwiki.com/index.php?title=CRC-16-CCITT

static ushort[] crc_table =  {
0x0000, 0x1021, 0x2042, 0x3063, 0x4084, 0x50a5,
0x60c6, 0x70e7, 0x8108, 0x9129, 0xa14a, 0xb16b,
0xc18c, 0xd1ad, 0xe1ce, 0xf1ef, 0x1231, 0x0210,
0x3273, 0x2252, 0x52b5, 0x4294, 0x72f7, 0x62d6,
0x9339, 0x8318, 0xb37b, 0xa35a, 0xd3bd, 0xc39c,
0xf3ff, 0xe3de, 0x2462, 0x3443, 0x0420, 0x1401,
0x64e6, 0x74c7, 0x44a4, 0x5485, 0xa56a, 0xb54b,
0x8528, 0x9509, 0xe5ee, 0xf5cf, 0xc5ac, 0xd58d,
0x3653, 0x2672, 0x1611, 0x0630, 0x76d7, 0x66f6,
0x5695, 0x46b4, 0xb75b, 0xa77a, 0x9719, 0x8738,
0xf7df, 0xe7fe, 0xd79d, 0xc7bc, 0x48c4, 0x58e5,
0x6886, 0x78a7, 0x0840, 0x1861, 0x2802, 0x3823,
0xc9cc, 0xd9ed, 0xe98e, 0xf9af, 0x8948, 0x9969,
0xa90a, 0xb92b, 0x5af5, 0x4ad4, 0x7ab7, 0x6a96,
0x1a71, 0x0a50, 0x3a33, 0x2a12, 0xdbfd, 0xcbdc,
0xfbbf, 0xeb9e, 0x9b79, 0x8b58, 0xbb3b, 0xab1a,
0x6ca6, 0x7c87, 0x4ce4, 0x5cc5, 0x2c22, 0x3c03,
0x0c60, 0x1c41, 0xedae, 0xfd8f, 0xcdec, 0xddcd,
0xad2a, 0xbd0b, 0x8d68, 0x9d49, 0x7e97, 0x6eb6,
0x5ed5, 0x4ef4, 0x3e13, 0x2e32, 0x1e51, 0x0e70,
0xff9f, 0xefbe, 0xdfdd, 0xcffc, 0xbf1b, 0xaf3a,
0x9f59, 0x8f78, 0x9188, 0x81a9, 0xb1ca, 0xa1eb,
0xd10c, 0xc12d, 0xf14e, 0xe16f, 0x1080, 0x00a1,
0x30c2, 0x20e3, 0x5004, 0x4025, 0x7046, 0x6067,
0x83b9, 0x9398, 0xa3fb, 0xb3da, 0xc33d, 0xd31c,
0xe37f, 0xf35e, 0x02b1, 0x1290, 0x22f3, 0x32d2,
0x4235, 0x5214, 0x6277, 0x7256, 0xb5ea, 0xa5cb,
0x95a8, 0x8589, 0xf56e, 0xe54f, 0xd52c, 0xc50d,
0x34e2, 0x24c3, 0x14a0, 0x0481, 0x7466, 0x6447,
0x5424, 0x4405, 0xa7db, 0xb7fa, 0x8799, 0x97b8,
0xe75f, 0xf77e, 0xc71d, 0xd73c, 0x26d3, 0x36f2,
0x0691, 0x16b0, 0x6657, 0x7676, 0x4615, 0x5634,
0xd94c, 0xc96d, 0xf90e, 0xe92f, 0x99c8, 0x89e9,
0xb98a, 0xa9ab, 0x5844, 0x4865, 0x7806, 0x6827,
0x18c0, 0x08e1, 0x3882, 0x28a3, 0xcb7d, 0xdb5c,
0xeb3f, 0xfb1e, 0x8bf9, 0x9bd8, 0xabbb, 0xbb9a,
0x4a75, 0x5a54, 0x6a37, 0x7a16, 0x0af1, 0x1ad0,
0x2ab3, 0x3a92, 0xfd2e, 0xed0f, 0xdd6c, 0xcd4d,
0xbdaa, 0xad8b, 0x9de8, 0x8dc9, 0x7c26, 0x6c07,
0x5c64, 0x4c45, 0x3ca2, 0x2c83, 0x1ce0, 0x0cc1,
0xef1f, 0xff3e, 0xcf5d, 0xdf7c, 0xaf9b, 0xbfba,
0x8fd9, 0x9ff8, 0x6e17, 0x7e36, 0x4e55, 0x5e74,
0x2e93, 0x3eb2, 0x0ed1, 0x1ef0
};

public static unsafe ushort CRC(byte* it, byte* end)
{
    ushort crc = 0;
    ushort temp;

    do
    {
        temp = (ushort)((*it ^ (crc >> 8)) & 0xff);
        crc = (ushort)(crc_table[temp] ^ (crc << 8));
    }
    while (it++ != end);

    return crc;
}
```